# Console access to Javascript variables local to the $(document).ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

How can I access some variables inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var foo=0;
    var bar = 3;
});
```

from Google chrome console? If I try alert(foo), I will get a message that it is not defined.

Comment: define them outside of $(document).ready( and then access them inside as well...

Comment: Are you sure jQuery is being loaded?

Comment: I don't want to declare them outside for security reasons, I'm just curious how or if they can be accessed with the console :)

Comment: @Vodaldrien: They can't.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192875/is-it-possible-to-gain-access-to-the-closure-of-a-function

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Put a breakpoint with the debugger. You'll get full access to them when the debugger will stop.

Other answers telling you to put them in the global scope are bad. Don't use bad practices just because you don't know how to use the right tools.

Comment: Could you link some information about this or what debugger should I use? Would be really appreciated. I'm new with javascript/jquery and I'm trying to check if those variables can be accessed in any way for security reasons. Thanks

Comment: @Voldadrien On Google Chrome it is built in, see chrome->tools->Developer Tools then click "Sources" and look at the right hand column... watch expressions, call stack, breakpoints, etc...

Comment: @Vodaldrien Use Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools. These variables *can* be accessed by whoever uses your code. In any case. Don't think you can secure your code this way. Once you give a webpage to a client, he can do anything he wants with it.

Comment: @Vodaldrien Hiding the variables is more about avoiding bugs and having a cleaner codebase :)

Comment: @RocketHazmat for Chrome Dev tools, look [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints). For Firebug, look into its doc.

Comment: this is the correct answer!

just type in `debugger` anywhere in your js. It can be anywhere, including definitions, not just procedural calls..

Answer (score 19):

You can't access these variables because they are defined within a functional closure. The only way you could do it is if you made a global reference to them outside your function's scope.

```
var foo, bar;

$(document).ready(function(){
    foo = 0;
    bar = 3;
});
```

Comment: 6 upvotes for an answer advising to use global variables? Really?

Comment: I'm not advising using globals, just that it's the only way to do this!

Comment: No, it's not. See my answer.

Comment: I think it's more important for the OP to understand closures than how to use debugging tools.

Comment: Learning how to use closures has nothing to do. You're advising global variables where it's not necessary.

Comment: At the risk of starting a flame war: "The only way you could do it..." doesn't imply advice, just a solution. The only solution within the context of the language is to use an external scope (e.g., global scope, or some other namespace). However, as you say, this restriction can be lifted using sophisticated debugging tools; but this is outside the specification of the language, itself.

Comment: If the code runs only once and you want to access local variables after completion - you have to expose it somehow. The debugger break point is a nice trick if you have the local variables accessible to functions that are currently running.

Answer (score 17):

Why not do a proper expose variable ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var foo=0;
    var bar = 3;

    $.exposed = {
        foo: foo,
        bar: bar
    }
});
```

Check your variables by doing

```
console.log($.exposed.bar)
```

Comment: Super useful for debugging! Nice.

Comment: This is a great idea and more cross browser suitable, although will have to be strict and not forget to remove them from here or use it as a shortcut, and then it becomes yet another window.variable problem. Otherwise, using `debugger;` is probably the best as it pretty much forces you to remove it before deployment.

Answer (score 5):

You can't since the are in a closure space. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) it explains how closure works ([How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) ).
To access the varible just set a breakpoint inside the `$(document).ready` function

Answer (score 4):

If you *really* need to access these variables from different parts of your code (initialize them on document ready, then accessing them elsewhere, for example), then you have to declare them outside the function closure.

If and only if this is the case, I'm not a fan of cluttering the global space. I would suggest you to use a base object for that :

```
var myObj = {};

$(function() {
   myObj.foo = 0;
   myObj.bar = 3;
});
```

**Note** that they will only be set once the document is loaded! Therefore `alert(myObj.foo);` (or something similar) place immediately after the `$(function() { ... });` block will yield `undefined`!

If you only need to access them inside that context, then do *not* declare anything outside the function. And try to debug your code with other methods. With chrome, `console.log` is quite helpful, for instance.

Comment: The amount of variables in is cut in half. It is definitely better than declaring two variables.

Comment: If the the variable `foo` *needs* to be accessed elsewhere, then you have no choice but to declare it outside, in a shared object. This is not bad practice, it is used all the time in JavaScript code. Some people abuse of it, but what I'm suggesting does not.

Comment: But it does not need to declared elsewhere.... did you even read the OPs question?

Comment: "Vote to remove this post" ? ... wow... I have read the question, and it is not specified. You speculate as much as I do, Neal.

Comment: Not sure why this answer got voted down. It basically says the same thing as the accepted answer, but adds only a single global object instead of a bunch of random global variables. This is definitely the best of the "make it global" answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.foo=0;
    window.bar = 3;
});
```

You expose those vars into global scope(really not advised)

Answer (score 1):

define them outside of $(document).ready() and then access them inside as well.

```
var foo = 0, bar = 3;
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert(foo);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a hackish way around it. You should probably not use it. Set a Breakpoint. That being said, here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(
    readyClosure = function(access){
        var x = 5; 
        return eval(access);
    }
);
readyClosure('x'); // returns 5
```