# How to access global variable of another jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ant, global-variables, overriding

I have two jquery functions (parent function and override function)

**parent function:**

```
( function ( $ )
{
    var one = null;
    var two = {};

    $.fn.method = function(){
    // parent code;
    }
   })( jQuery );
```

**OverRide function:**

```
( function ( $ )
{

$.fn.method = function(){
    // override code;
  }
  })( jQuery );
```

which is working as expected. but when i try to access the variable one or two, i can't. Do u know why? is there any option to access the variable one and two from override function without modifying the parent?

Note : in my case parent and override are two seperate js files merged to one common js while put build via ant.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't. What you have here is a closure and a point about closures is that you can't access their variable from elsewhere.

If you want to access them, you must add accessors :

```
( function ( $ )
    {
        var one = null;
        var two = {};

        $.fn.method = function(){
        // parent code;
        }
        $.fn.getOne = function() {
            return one;
        };
        $.fn.setOne = function(n) {
            return one = n;
        };
})( jQuery );
```

You might be interested in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192875/is-it-possible-to-gain-access-to-the-closure-of-a-function).