# access object from other scope (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to gain access to the closure of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192875/is-it-possible-to-gain-access-to-the-closure-of-a-function)

Please have a look at this code: http://jsfiddle.net/FH6pB/1/

```
(function($) {
  var o1 = {
    init: function() { alert('1'); },
  }
  var o2 = {
    init: function() { alert('2'); },
  }
}(jQuery));

(function($) {
  var o3 = {
    init: function() { alert('3'); },
  }
  o2.init();
}(jQuery));


o1.init();
o2.init();
```

I have 3 object in 2 different "scopes" (I don't know if it's the right word to use here, but I guess you understand the meaning).
As you probably know, I can't access the objects' function from either outside or other "scope" (non of the `o.init();` will work).

Why does it happen? Is there a way to change it?

I know I can just put the code in one scope and it will work well, but what if I have scopes in separate JS file?

Thanks from advance, 
Ben

Comment: There is no code in the fiddle.

Comment: Please don't only put your code in the fiddle, put it in the question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't access variables declared in a closure from outside. That's simply how closure work.

A (generally bad) solution, would be to declare the variables as global ones :

```
(function($) {
  window.o2 = {
    init: function() { alert('2'); },
  };
}(jQuery));

o2.init();
```

But usually, the module pattern is used to make private some variables and only return the useful ones. See [this article](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a namespace-like:

http://jsfiddle.net/FH6pB/2/

```
var scope = {};

(function($) {
  scope.o1 = {
    init: function() { alert('1'); },
  }
  scope.o2 = {
    init: function() { alert('2'); },
  }
}(jQuery));

(function($) {
  scope.o3 = {
    init: function() { alert('3'); },
  }
  scope.o2.init();
}(jQuery));


scope.o1.init();
scope.o2.init();
```