# How to put google places api working code under IIFE

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

```
var calli = (function(){

    var inputbox, geocoder;

function initAutocomplete() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  inputbox = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
             (document.getElementById('input-box')), {
              types: ['geocode']
             });


  inputbox.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);  
}

function fillInAddress() {
  var getplace = inputbox.getPlace();
  codeAddress(document.getElementById('input-box').value);
}

function codeAddress(address) {
   geocoder.geocode({
           'address': address
            }, 
            function(results, status) {
              if (status == 'OK') 
                 { console.log('hi');
                   var senddata = $.get('/myurl',{params}, function (data) {});

               } else {
                       alert( status);
                  }
            });
}

 return (initAutocomplete); 
 })();

calli();
```

When I use above code without an IIFE it works fine, gives the autocomplete drop down list.
But, when I use it like above, nothing happens, no error, only `AuthenticationService` gets called, and no call to `AutocompletionService.GetPridictions?` happens.

Any suggestion as to where I am wrong? Thank you very much.iife

Comment: Please show your working code,

Comment: Where is `initAutocomplete` being called?

Comment: Not completely sure. It seems to be something automatically loaded using the addon that you're using (it's referenced in the URL, I believe). The easiest way to fix that would be to use `window.initAutocomplete = initAutocomplete` inside the IIFE.

Comment: @h2ooooooo :Please see the 3 edits just made, in the very first line assigned a `var calli` , returning `initAutocomplete` and in the last line calling `calli()`. No error, nothing

Comment: @h2ooooooo : Ok, sir, trying what you are suggesting.

Comment: @JackBashford : I am not allowed to put in any code, Sir. It says 'looks like your post is mostly code, please add some details'. Upon putting out those 3 functions -  `initAutocomplete(){}`, `codeAddress(){}`, `fillInAddress(){}` it works nicely.