# How to pass a message from one react app to another on the same page using postMessage() and eventListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make 2 react app versions communicate with each other (react 16 to 15). I want to pass a message from my react16 app to my react15 in a one-way manner. I did not find it viable to upgrade the old app to a newer version since I only need something to work for the meantime while we develop a newer version.

So what my react 16 app does basically is it already sends a message to a chrome extension and the extension will, in turn, return a dataUrl. An the dataUrl would then be rendered to a canvas then after editing the image it would send it to firebase using axios for storage. Firebase will then have a response that I would want to be sent to the react 15 app using an event listener.

What I tried is that when the image is successfully sent to the database the react 16 app will do a window.postMessage(). The older app has an eventlistener on componentDidMount() which supposedly should catch the message.

When I make this run It won't work though. The postMessage is okay but it seems like the eventListener isn't catching it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

React 16 app
**ImageContainer.js**

```
...
        axios.post('/screenshots.json', submittedImage)
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({ showPrompt: false })

                response.status === 200 ? this.props.notify(true, "Screenshot Saved! ") : this.props.notify(false)

                this.props.storeImageToArrayHandler(submittedImage)
                let firebaseId = response.data.name                 // This will be used for single querying the image from firebase

                let feedBackButton = document.getElementById('feedback-button');

                feedBackButton.click();

                var data = { type: "FROM_REACT16", text: "Enter Image ID" };
                console.log("[ImageContainer] Sending Message...")
                window.postMessage(data, "*");
                this.setState({ showImageContainer: false })

            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.setState({ showPrompt: false })
                this.props.notify(false, "Unable to save Screenshot. " + error)
                this.props.storeImageToArrayHandler("")
            })
...
```

React 15 app
**MainContainer.js**

```
...
componentDidMount() {
    console.log("[componentDidMount] MainContainer.js")

    window.addEventListener("image_interceptor", function (event) { //listen for messages from react app
      console.log("[MainContainer] Listening for messages...")
      if (event.data.type && (event.data.type === "FROM_REACT16")) {
        console.log('I got the message');
      }
      return true;
    });

    window.mainContainer = {
      addStateValidator: this.addStateValidator,
    };
    this.props.start();
  }
...
```

**index.html**

```
...
<BODY>
<div style=" width: 100%; height:100%; position: absolute;; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0;">
    <div id="notification" style="display:inline;">
      <p>Extension not detected.
        You can download the extension <a
          href="www.link-to-extension.com">here</a>
        .
      </p>

    </div>
</div>
<div id="root"></div>                             //REACT 15
<div id="screenshot"></div>                       //REACT 16

<script src="feedback/feedback-main.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="feedback/bundle.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: as I understand postMessage is intended to communicate between windows. In your case maybe it is enough to use global objects

Comment: I think this should work for my use case but this topic mentions that I should avoid using it: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45080011/global-variable-for-react

Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: it is not actually like that. In this case you need to communicate between two apps. you can take a look at my answer at another thread about global things, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55433913/should-global-variables-in-javascript-be-always-avoided/55439714#55439714.