# How find variable/array if I don't know full variable name in javascript

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I am trying to get additional information from site and there is variable/array that defined randomly. Like this:

```
var firstvar_numbers= "already exist"
var secondvar_numbers= ["a","b","c","d"]
```

numbers is random value that given by site. In firefox DOM when I wrote half of `secondvar_` it immediately find that I wanted because there is only one variable that starts with `second`. My question is how I can get value/array of variable in userscript/javascript by knowing part of the variable.
Example if you don't understood:
Html

```
//Variable that I need from server
<div id="variables" class="container">

<script type="text/javascript">
var exists_73647286="hello world"

var array_636353=[62,96,11,28]
</script>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
//Code that will get array
alert("exists_"+seconpartofvar())
function seconpartofvar(){your code}
```

OR

```
alert(autocomplate.exists_)
```

Here I can write `alert(exists_)` in Firefox console and it will recommend autocomplate.

Comment: If varaibles are defiend in global scope, those will be under `window` object. `Object.keys(window)` will give you an array of all keys. you can then apply regular expression match on all keys to find out specific patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's declared with `var` on the top level, you can iterate over the properties of the `window` and find one which `startsWith` what you're looking for:

```js
// Example site code:
var array_636353 = [62, 96, 11, 28];

// Userscript code:
const prop = Object.keys(window).find(key => key.startsWith('array_'));
console.log(prop, window[prop]);
```

Comment: Nice! Do you know how to resolve the scoped variables?

Comment: @Yusifx1 `document.getElementById('#variables')` ?

Comment: @Supercool. For true access, you can use a MutationObserver to watch for the addition of the `<script>` tag and replace it with your own needed functionality: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59424277 If the variable stays constant, you can also use a regular expression to look through the `textContent` of the script tag and see what gets assigned to the variable

Comment: If the site has multiple elements with the same ID, that's invalid HTML... but you can still iterate over the elements with the query string `[id="variables"]` - pass it to `querySelectorAll` and then you'll be able to iterate over them.

Comment: Final question. Should I get only variable from div or it wouldn't slow down browser/JavaScript/site if I use "window" with thousands variable?

Comment: @Yusifx1 A thousand operations isn't much on a modern computer, especially if you're just iterating over the properties of an object, even if it's the window object, that's quite cheap given modern computers. If you had to do it in a *tight loop*, on the other hand, that could be a problem, but that's rare.