# Is there a way to detect if a console user is changing a varible

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to prevent cheating on my game by not letting console user change variables through the console, is there a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to enclose your whole script into an IIFE. For example, change:

```
var points = 0;
// do stuff with points
```

to

```
(() => {
  var points = 0;
  // do stuff with points
})();
```

This way, it will be *markably more difficult* to change `points` from outside by the user - but it [won't be completely impossible.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59424277)

(Also make sure not to store any variables on the window - define them inside closures instead, like above)

Fundamentally, all code executed user-side is untrustworthy. The only way to be sure that something is legitimate is to do all the verifications on the server instead.