# Are there really no private variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop, es6-class

Private variables are variables that are visible only to the class to which they belong. It is a common opinion that there are no strict private variables in JS (except for the new fields like this.#property).
Can anyone kindly explain why the variable 'boy' bellow cannot be considered to be a private one?

```
class Forrest {
  constructor() {
    let boy = "Bobby"
    this.getBoy = function() {
      console.log(boy)
    }
  }
}

const f = new Forrest()
f.getBoy() // Bobby
```

Comment: The `let boy` is in a closure, so sure looks pretty private to me. Closures are private - *mostly* https://stackoverflow.com/a/59424277

Comment: There's experimental support for private fields - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Which OP mentioned in the question

Comment: JavaScript only recently has classes. Without classes the private/public visibility question doesn't make sense. There are only variables, and their scope.

Comment: @OrangeDog - The pattern above was common with just constructor functions, too. There's nothing in the question (other than `let`) that wouldn't be virtually identical with an ES5 constructor function.

Comment: There's nothing non-private about `boy` in your example. In any OO language I've ever seen, a public getter can access any private variable; it's an *extremely* common pattern in Java, for example.

Comment: As CertainPerformance and Pointy have already said, that `boy` is pretty darned private. :-) Note that regardless of how you feel about the closure approach above, though, JavaScript [will have true private fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) very, very soon. It's implemented in most major engines and likely to hit the spec this year.

Comment: "*Private variables are variables that are visible only to the class to which they belong.*" given this definition, why do you believe `boy` is visible *to the class*?

Comment: @VLAZ Because we can access it via method getBoy, defined in this class.

Comment: @MaksymDudyk because it's private *to the constructor*. But if you declare a normal method, then that variable is not visible there. Ergo, it's not visible *to the class*.

Comment: @VLAZ If we are looking for a variable only 'visible to the class', we would pick up a static variable.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't heard people claim that `boy` in your example isn't private. Quite the opposite, it's private to the constructor and `getBoy`. Nothing else (including nothing else in that class) can access it. But either way, I suppose that might be in the "opinion-based" realm.

Stepping out of that realm: Regardless of someone may feel about the closure approach shown in the question, JavaScript [will have true private fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) very, very soon. It's implemented in most major engines and likely to hit the spec this year. Your example with private fields looks like this:

```js
class Forrest {
    #boy = "Bobby";

    getBoy() {
        console.log(this.#boy);
    }
}

const f = new Forrest();
f.getBoy() // Bobby
```

Or if we set it from a constructor parameter:

```js
class Forrest {
    #boy;
    constructor(boy) {
        this.#boy = boy;
    }

    getBoy() {
        console.log(this.#boy);
    }
}

const f = new Forrest("Bobby");
f.getBoy() // Bobby
```

Those will run on up-to-date versions of Chromium-based browsers. Safari and Firefox won't be much longer.

Comment: Thank you, T.J. These 'true private fields' which are comming, do you think we'd better call them 'protected' not 'private', since we can access them from inherited classes like this: class Forrest {
    #boy = "Bobby";
    getBoy() {
      console.log(this.#boy);
    }
}

class Holt extends Forrest {
  getIt() {
    return this.getBoy();
  }
}


var h = new Holt()
h.getIt(); // Bobby

Comment: @MaksymDudyk - No. The *field* is private. What you're doing there is providing a **public** accessor for the field. That accessor is public (you don't even need `Holt`, you could just it outside any class), but the *field* is private. If the field were protected, you could use it via `this.#boy` in `Holt`, which you can't.