# GreaseMonkey: on a webpage with Monaco editor, how to find instance of Monaco class?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, monaco-editor

I am a JavaScript noob, pardon if my question is too silly or ill stated.

I am trying to figure out how to write a GreaseMonkey script that would detect whether there is a monaco editor on a webpage, and if there is one, then it would try to retrieve  its contents. It seems to be easy to do as long as I have an instance of Monaco editor, but I am struggling to figure out how to find it from within GreaseMonkey script.

Basically, here is an example page with Monaco: https://app.coderpad.io/sandbox

From what I understand, a line like this is executed somewhere to initialize Monaco:

```
let editor = monaco.editor.create.create(...);
```

And then the reference to this `editor` could either be dropped, or not saved in any standard place. At  least I wasn't able to find it in `document.*` or `window.*`. I only found global variable `window.MonacoEnvironment`, but it doesn't appear to contain any useful references to editor object itself.

I also read source code of Monaco and found   `monaco.editor.getEditors()` function. But I am JavaScript noob and can't figure out why it doesn't work - in Chrome console:

```
monaco.editor.getEditors()
Uncaught ReferenceError: monaco is not defined
```

Is there a way to import monaco namespace to make this expression to work?

In general, how can I find reference to `editor` object(s) from within  GreaseMonkey script, that would work reliably on any webpage using reasonably recent version of Monaco? Or is this even possible?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: 99% chance this is impossible. Larger apps are usually bundled up and wrapped up in an IIFE, so the only way to do that is to manually alter the JS.

Comment: @code Not impossible. (1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192875/is-it-possible-to-gain-access-to-the-closure-of-a-function (2) Sometimes editors like these are explicitly added as a property of an element - if you can access the element, you can access the editor. Monaco may work the same way (or maybe not).

Comment: At first glance, I don't see the editor being accessible outside, so I'd use the technique described https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192875/is-it-possible-to-gain-access-to-the-closure-of-a-function to overwrite the code to add a line `window.theEditor = editor` or something like that

Comment: @CertainPerformance,
This trick might work if given code is present inside html page. However in my case javascript is loaded from another URL via  `<script src="..."></script>` - can your  method be extended to this  case?

Comment: Yes it can - use a MutationObserver to watch for the attachment of the script to the document, and then you can replace the script's `src` with a blank one, and set its `.textContent` to your altered script text. More generally, if this is only for *you* personally, you can also use Chrome Local Overrides instead. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59518023